# Plotting last data block in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose I have a data file divided into blocks as follws

```
0     0
1     2
2     0


0     5
1     3
2     4


0     -1
1     3
2     5


...
```

Is there any way to tell gnuplot to plot only the last block?

Comment: Using `index`? Try gnuplot online help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access an arbitrary block you can use `index`. Unfortunately, you cannot access "the last block" without knowing its index. So you must use `stats` to get the number of blocks:

```
stats 'file.dat' using 1
plot 'file.dat' index STATS_blocks-1
```